# Android: Launching ListFragments as individual fragments from another activity?

Tags: android, list, android-fragments

I'm working on an app that uses a navigation drawer, with each menu items intended to launch a particular fragment. And each fragment must be in a list view form. Is there a way to launch the listfragments as normal fragment can be launched?

For instance:

```
new MyListFragment();
```

Is there a similar way to launch listfragments from the main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments are never "launched," they are added to Activities. Either add the fragment to the current activity using a [`FragmentTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) (perhaps by replacing the content area), or start another activity with that fragment in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void goToRadar(FragmentManager fm){
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.flMain, new ChildRadarFragment());
    ft.addToBackStack("radar");
    ft.commit();
}
```

You must have a FrameLayout inside the xml-layout of your Activity (here the id = flMain).
You should do the FragmentTransactions when a menu listitem is clicked (=drawer ListView).

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int index,
                long arg3) {
        // Here the FragmentTransaction
    }
});
```